# Expected value that depends on Poisson distribution

Tags: expected-value, poisson-distribution

X = The number of customers entering a shop.
X∼Poisson(4)

P(Costumer buys 1 pair of socks) = 3/4.

decisions are not dependent.

Y random variable that equals the number of socks sold.

What is E[Y]?

---

Would like to get some help with this question, I got a hint that its between [3,3.5)
but not sure how to get the exact value..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a single customer purchase more than one pair of socks?

Comment: No, each costumer buys one.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$P(X=n)=\frac{4^ne^{-4}}{n!}$$
The expected number of socks bought if $n$ customers enter is $\frac34n$. Then
$$E(Y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^ne^{-4}}{n!}\cdot\frac34n$$
$$=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^{n-1}e^{-4}}{(n-1)!}$$
$$=3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^ne^{-4}}{n!}=3$$
The following more general property holds: if $X\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $Y$ given $X=k$ follows $\operatorname{binom}(k,p)$, then $Y\sim\operatorname{Pois}(p\lambda)$.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did something very similar but for some reason i replace 3/4*n
with 3/4..

Comment: What Parcly is applying here is called [The law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).